# Remove div without class when contains custom element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove stray elements. Some have no `class` or `id` attributes whom specifically have a custom element also without an `id` or `class` attribute. However there are some cases where the custom element does have a class name.

The only P that should remain, have either text only or a Video element.

```
$("p:contains("$("getimage")")").remove();
```

Is there a better way to get this to work?

EDIT

"getimage" is the custom tag.

```
<div class="ajaxPostText">
<p><getimage style="display:none;" height="360" width="640" src="http://localhost:8888/localTesting/wp-content/plugins/wp-o-matic/cache/687a91dca2_ku-xlarge.jpg" class="transform-ku-xlarge"></getimage></p>
<p>Movies are too long. Even film masterpieces can shave off a few minutes here and there so we can get off our butts, away from laptops, out of theaters, eyeballs off the TV a little bit earlier. So. How short can a movie be for you to get the gist of it? Can it be done in nine single frames?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `$("getimage")` here...?

Comment: Can you show your html code?

Comment: you don't have any candidates in your example html to remove.  The first `p` has a `getimage` with a `class`.  The second `p` has no `getimage`. can you provide more html or edit your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove all p tags without id and class.  Included a demo with a sample getImage tag too.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MgCeC/)

```
$('p').not('[id],[class]').remove();
```

If you want to remove for all elements inside a container.

```
$('*','.containerSelector').not('[id],[class]').remove();
```

For the specific example that you have provided try this:- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EFHCZ/)

```
$('*', '.ajaxPostText').not('[id],[class]').remove();
```

More filter:- This will remove the p tags with no id, no class, no text. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RjccE/)

```
$('p', '.ajaxPostText').not('[id],[class]').filter(function(){
     return  $.trim($(this).text()) === '' 
}).remove();
```

Comment: This looks and works really well! Is there a variation where if a P has only text (as above example), that stays visible?

Comment: @canacast Yes it is possible through filter to check that.. But what is there are any other attributes at all?

Comment: You wan to make `p` stay even if it has only the text?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. Some P will have the custom element, some have A tags within them. The ones that should stay only have text or a Video element. I had no idea all these options were available until now! Wow.

Comment: i think you mean "custom attributes" or "custom classes", not "custom elements", yes?

Comment: FTR, which one was good @canacast?  your question is not clear if the first or second group of code examples here helps?

Comment: @canacast Not quite sure what yo uneed but i have update my answer with filter option. Probably you can improve on it based on what you need.